# Visual Studio - Platform

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, platform

I have several projects in a solution. The projects are written in: C++, C++/CLI, C#.

The goal is to have an selection for only x86/x64 platform, not Win32, x86, x86, Mixed, AnyCPU.

I cannot change C++ platform target to x86 only to Win32. How can I do that, or how can I mask so that I have only x86/x64  selection in tool manager ?
(the compilation is done only for Intel/AMD cpus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Menu Build > Configuration Manager, you can edit all configuration for the solution. You can have a solution named as you want (when selection "new" in *Active solution platform*, you can write the name you want) and assign wich configuration you want for each project (Win32, x86, and so on ...)

What you see in VS2012's toolbar, it's the active solution platform. If you want it to be named "My platform for x86", you can do it;)